# Uploading a Single Page Application in Angular with Laravel Backend on Shared Hosting

Tags: angular, laravel, single-page-application, shared-hosting

I have created a Single Page Application using Angular 8 which consumes a backend API build using Laravel. Everyting is working well on my local machine. Now I want to upload it on a shared hosting via CPanel. I have uploaded the Laravel project inside public_html folder.

When I compile the Angular project using ng-build, where will I put the dist folder in my Laravel project so that the SPA is served using Laravel on the backend.

Comment: Does your hosting provider support `.htaccess` files, and is/was there a `index.html` in your `public_html` folder?

Comment: @Reactgular Yes the hosting supports .htaccess file,, in my public folder (in Laravel) there is index.php file..

Comment: That's good. Do you want to host your Angular app in the root domain like this `http://www.example.com/` or in a child folder `http://www.example.com/app/`?

Comment: @rectangular ,, I want to host it in a child folder,, I want to use a subdomain which I have already configured on c-panel,, for instance I want to use `test-app.example.com` for the angular app  while my live website domain runs  on `example.com`

Comment: @rectangular,, I have created a subfolder inside public_html (in cpanel) called test-app whereby my subdomain points to..

Comment: @Reactgular Waiting for a response from your end

Comment: @Reactgular I have reframed my question to be a bit clear,, please check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912465/uploading-angular-and-laravel-on-a-shared-hosting-via-cpanel)

Comment: Copy the contents of your `dist` folder to the sub-folder for the sub-domain, and then try adding a `.htaccess` file to that sub-folder. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566